# advnce dml : mysql insert into a column

Tags: mysql

I HAVE ADD ONE MORE ELEMENT TO MY TABLE EMPLOYEE AND I HAD ASKED TO use into a column ALLOWANCE with an amount of 500 and i need to assign a value 0 for those who are not entitled for allowance . DO i need to use IFNULL Function for this if i want to assign value 0 for those who are not entitled with allowance ?? can someone teach me how to do that ?

```
 ALTER TABLE Employee 
ADD (ALLOWANCE DECIMAL (5,2) ;

 INSERT INTO Employee (ALLOWANCE)
 values (500)
WHERE DNo = (select DNo FROM Department where DName ='SALES' );
```

Comment: You need UPDATE not INSERT

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Comment: I think he is just emphasizing in the keywords rather than shouting.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I DON'T THINK SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
ALTER TABLE Employee 
ADD ALLOWANCE DECIMAL (5,2) DEFAULT 0;
```

Then use update command like this -

```
UPDATE Employee E JOIN Department D
       ON E.DNo = D.DNo
SET ALLOWANCE = 500
WHERE DName ='SALES';
```